# How on earth will anyone prove $n^3-3n^2+n-1=Θ(n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I know its homework question.Sorry for that.But i was solving all problems of Skiena and chapter and got stuck to this problem of 2nd chapter 2.10.

Its easy to prove $n^3-3n^2+n-1=O(n^3)$ because $n^3-3n^2+n-1<=c.n^3$ for any $c>=1$

but how $n^3-3n^2+n-1=Ω(n^3)$ is possible.How to show $n^3-3n^2+n-1>=c.n^3$ for all values of $c>=1$ ?

Comment: I don't know how much machinery your book develops, so don't know whether this will be helpful. One can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-3n^2+n-1}{n^3}=1$ by dividing top and bottom by $n^3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I tried this way but book says f(n) dominates g(n) only if $lim_{n→∞}g(n)/(n)=0$ clearly it is not achievable from limits.right?

Comment: you should write down the definition of what it means to be a $\Theta(n^3)$

Comment: Big theta holds if there are positive constants $c$ and $d$ such that in the long run $f(n)\lt cg(n)$ and $g(n)\lt df(n)$. So no dominance, it means roughly the same size. I think you may be misreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :Use limits to show that the quotient approaches one . Then use the definition of limit to show existence of the required constants

Comment: I tried to using limits and dominance relations.But books says only if limits tend to ∞ or 0 then dominance relations can be applied.Can i use Θ when limits tends to constant also?

Comment: Yes you can, it follows from the definition